# How do I store a list of items referenced by key in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to store a collection of items in javascript. I need to be able to delete them by key. This is a crud application. What's the best way to do this?

Do I need to remove the item with a splice from a standard array and then update the array to remove the missing space?

Comment: Searching for the words JavaScript and key should be enough to lead you to the answer. Just use a plain object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question is sounds like you are trying to do this using an array. It would be a lot easier to use an object as a key-value store. E.g.,

```
var collection = {};
```

Then, to add an item with a key:

```
collection[key] = item;
```

To get an item:

```
var item = collection[key];
```

And to delete an item:

```
delete collection[key];
```

If you want things to be easy, it is important to use a strings for keys. A key will be implicitly converted to a string using [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString). This does not yield a useful result (unless overridden) if you try using an object as a key because it will be converted to the string `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. So I am guessing doing it this way is pretty normal for keeping relational data in the browser?

Comment: @Exitos It is very common. Example: jQuery internally uses plain objects for caching and storing data attributes and arbitrary data accessed via [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).